# Oracle/ PLSQL- Substring Till Next Occurence of Character

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string

```
myString = "C=3;A=1;B=2;"
```

from which I'm trying to extract the value of `A` as follows

```
SELECT
  SUBSTR(myString,
         INSTR(myString, 'A='),
         INSTR(myString, ';')-1
        ) AS val_a
FROM DUAL;
```

which gives me the following result

```
+-------+
| Val_A | 
+-------+
|  A=1  |
+-------+
```

But I just want the value of `A`. So I tried to add 2 to the second parameter of `SUBSTR`

```
SUBSTR(myString,
       INSTR(myString, 'A=')+2,
       INSTR(myString, ';')-1
      )
```

but that gave me

```
+-------+
| Val_A | 
+-------+
|  1;B  |
+-------+
```

Could someone please tell me how to get just the part between `A=` and the next `;`?

Comment: The third parameter of `SUBSTR` is the length of the substring you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a regular expression and `regexp_substr()`

```
with data (mystring) as (
   select 'C=3;A=;B=2;' from dual union all
   select 'C=3;A=1;B=2;' from dual union all
   select 'C=3;A=12;B=2;' from dual union all
   select 'C=3;A=123;B=2;' from dual
)
select mystring, regexp_substr(mystring, '(A=)([^\;)]*)', 1, 1, 'i', 2) as aval
from data;
```

<sup>(The `with data (...)` part is only there to generate some testdata)</sup>

returns

```
MYSTRING       | AVAL
---------------+-----
C=3;A=;B=2;    |     
C=3;A=1;B=2;   | 1   
C=3;A=12;B=2;  | 12  
C=3;A=123;B=2; | 123
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if there is `A=12` then this query would still return `1`. How could I select the substring after `A=` and before `;`? I checked the documentation for `regexp_substr` but couldn't find what I wanted :(

Comment: This will fail for the input `'C=3;AA=1;A=4;B=2;'`.

Answer (score 1):

Without regular expressions:

```
WITH data ( mystring ) AS (
  SELECT 'C=3;AA=1;A=4;B=2;' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT SUBSTR( mystring, val_a_start, val_a_end - val_a_start ) AS val_a
FROM   (
  SELECT mystring,
         INSTR( mystring, ';A=' ) + 3 AS val_a_start,
         INSTR( mystring, ';', INSTR( mystring, ';A=' ) + 3 ) AS val_a_end
  FROM   (
   SELECT ';' || mystring || ';' AS mystring
   FROM   data
  )
)
```

With regular expressions:

```
WITH data ( mystring ) AS (
  SELECT 'C=3;AA=1;A=4;B=2;' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( ';' || mystring || ';', ';A=(.*?);', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS val_a
FROM   data
```